# How to know the current url when using MemoryRouter

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router

I'm trying to figure out how to use a test to assert what the current location pathname is.

As an experiment [and based on some docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md) I wrote the following test

```
  test(`Can navigate MemoryRouter`, (done) => {
    const logAll = (p, ...args) => {
      console.log(`SOME OUTPUT`,p, ...args)
      return p.location.pathname
    }

    const div = document.createElement('div')

    const Test = () => (
      <MemoryRouter>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Link to="/foo/bar" id="click-me" />
          <Route render={logAll} />
        </React.Fragment>
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Test), div)
    console.log('click')
    Simulate.click(div.querySelector('#click-me'))
  })
```

I would expect because the `logAll` route matches all changes for it to log once at `/` (which it does) and then again at `/foo/bar`. But the latter never logs before the test times out (about 5 seconds).

What am I missing?

Comment: are you missing to call `done()`?

Comment: @Alex yes, I don't have a call to `done` nor an assertion, I am not expecting the test to pass, I am expecting the pathname to get logged twice, this isn't a real test, just a way to run some exploratory code. I'm not calling `done` at the moment because I wanted to give plenty of time for the navigation to work in case it was async. Currently it gets logged only once before the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is ok (you even don't need `done`), however second argument of `Simulate.click` is missed. If you add it, it'll work as you expect:

```
Simulate.click(
    div.querySelector('#click-me'),
    { button: 0 }
);
```

Look at [the codebase](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L25) shows that `Link` does not proceed clicks that have no `button=0` in event.

[Blame of this line](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blame/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L25), shows that `Link` [tracks only **left button** click](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5468).

Comment: Oh for chrissake...thank you! This is ... dumb...why would that not be the default?

Comment: Yeah, confusing... I checked [enzyme's simulate](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html) - it works the same way. Maybe suggest them? But I guess they'll reject as it might have bad side effect. You can define something like `SimulateLeftClick.click()` wrapper helper in your test to handle this.